# How to translate French "colleur"/"khôlleur" position into english?

Tags: undergraduate, job, translations, preparation, france

French higher education system is quite singular: besides traditional universities (following Bologna Process scheme with Bachelor (3 years), Master (2 years) and PhD (3 years)), there are so-called [*grandes écoles*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandes_%C3%A9coles) – mostly in the business and engineering fields. To enter a *grande école*, one must traditionally attend [*classes préparatoires*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classe_pr%C3%A9paratoire_aux_grandes_%C3%A9coles).

One distinctive feature of these *classes prépa* is the significance of frequent *colles* (1 every two weeks per student and discipline – sometimes also written *khôlles*), which generally consist of  1 hour oral examination, where a couple of undergrads solve a problem in front of an examiner – the so-colled *colleur*.

*Colleurs* are mostly professors teaching in *classe prépa*. However they can also be university assistant professors, high-school teachers, PhD-candidates, or post-doc lecturing on their part time.

**Question:** What is the most appropriate translation of "*colleur*" into English?

("TA" or "tutor" both seem too broad in my opinion.)

Comment: The term TA (and "undergrads") usually refer to university-level settings. I wouldn't use them in the context of pre-university teaching.

Comment: How this is different from "examiner"?

Comment: @svavil I'd say it would be too vague, or doesn't sound (for me, as foreigner) as a proper job title... I might however be wrong!

Comment: @CapeCode: I understand. However, *classes prépa* are not "pre-university" per se - it's rather a parralel track, since most classes prépa student don't do to university. Students in "classes prépa" are at the same level as first and second-year bachelor students.

Comment: @ebo If examiner is too vague, you can always add some complementary information in the job title, e.g., the discipline or the _lycée_.  This also gives you the opportunity to give a brief description of what khôlles are, what topics were treated, etc.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out, if the "so-cOlled" colleur is a typo or a pun.  Or both.

Comment: The Wikipedia articles do not really give information about those exams. Do the colleurs also teach or are they only doing the exams?

Comment: @skymningen I'd love to say it was deliberate... *Per se*, colleurs do not teach to full class (except if they have other jobs), even if *colles* aims both at examining students (primary goal), but also at beeing the place for extra-tutoring (i.e. re-explaining the lesson to a student who fails at solving a problem).

Answer (score 10):

I would suggest using the official title and then adding a brief sentence describing the job duties. This way you provide ask the information in an accurate and accessible way. Having to look up a job title is not a big deal when evaluating foreigners.

Comment: I agree. The job sounds particular enough that mapping it to job titles in universities that don't have anything comparable is only bound to confuse.

Comment: I think that’s the best option too. I have never really seen something similar outside the classes prépa in France (I was in classe prépa myself). For the job duties I would write something like "Examiner for weekly oral interrogations in small groups (x hours and y students in total, over z months)."

Answer (score 1):

In English universities, the equivalent exam is usually called a "viva", short for ["viva voce"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_exam).  We do not have a specific word for a person who assesses oral exams though, I'm afraid, so "viva examiner" is probably the best you're going to get.

Comment: But isn't the "viva" normally the PhD defense? If that's the case, "viva examiner" sounds like an opponent in a PhD defense (i.e., something completely different).

Comment: @xLeitix a viva can be used for any exam/assessment which involves some delivery and q&a - that style is not limited to PhD afaik...

Comment: @xLeitix As Mike says, a PhD always involves a viva, but not all vivas are for PhDs. My ex-wife had vivas for some of her undergraduate philosophy modules, and for her final-year project.